# Casting NodeList to Array.<HTMLElement> in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am looking for a way to get all the children `HTMLElement` of an `HTMLElement` in javascript. I used `childNodes` but I am having trouble casting a `NodeList` to an `Array.<HTMLElement>` as they are not subtypes of each other (I am using Google Closure Compiler to enforce typing).

Here is an example that returns a warning:

```
/** @type {Array.<HTMLElement>} */
var kids = /** @type {Array.<HTMLElement>} */ (document.childNodes);
```

It returns

```
test.js:2: WARNING - invalid cast - must be a subtype or supertype
from: NodeList
to  : (Array.<(HTMLElement|null)>|null)
var kids = /** @type {Array.<HTMLElement>} */ (document.childNodes);
                                               ^
```

As all `childNodes` are not `HTMLElements` I can understand the warning but is there a work around?

=== EDIT ===

Surprisingly, I am having no problem casting a `Node` to an `HTMLElement`. The problem comes from casting a `NodeList` to an `Array.<Node>`.

Comment: Maybe John can answer this one. I usually have to settle for a type union: `@type {Array.<HTMLElement>|NodeList}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the compiler is correct in this case - NodeLists are not Arrays nor are they even related. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

You need to augment your type definition with a union of both types:

```
/** @type {Array.<Node>|NodeList} */
var kids = document.childNodes;
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe that's it, you cannot do that in one step, you either construct your array by hand by adding each `Node` or use this trick which is a bit contradictory with the concept of enforcing type...

Comment: A great post on the difference: http://duruk.net/nodelists-and-arrays-in-javascript/